# What is the meaning of "guide" in "if the number of demands for implementing reforms is any guide"?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence in [The Hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/a-solution-in-search-of-a-problem/article25962037.ece) which was:

> If the number of demands for implementing reforms is any guide, India's reservation system is clearly in disarray.

How do both parts of sentence relate and what is the meaning of "guide" in that context?

Comment: @laurel how did you shorten the link?

Comment: I used markdown: `[Link description](https://example.com)`. The link you had was messed up so I went and found the article through Google and copied the link from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Guide' here is a noun, meaning "something that helps you form an opinion or make a decision about something else". If the number of demands for implementing reforms is "any guide" (is a reliable indication), then, says The Hindu newspaper, India's reservation system is clearly in disarray. If the amount of smoke is any guide, that building over there is burning! If the smell is any guide, this piece of meat is not fit to eat. If the expression on my father's face is any guide, he is very angry.

[Guide (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guide)